# Graph alignment

Tags: tikz-trees

I am new to tikz and have been doing some exercises. I came acros an example of a small bayesian network in the book "*Probabilistic Graphical Models*" and thought I'd try to draw. The `graphs` seemed the best choice where nodes are defined by connecting them but the module places all nodes in somewhat odd way. Here's the picture

[image]

and here is the code:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, graphs, matrix, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \graph[grow down, grow down sep=3mm, branch right=2.5cm,
        edges={>=Latex, semithick, color=black},
        nodes={draw, ellipse, fill=black!10, very thick,
        minimum width=2cm, minimum height=10mm}] {
        GC -> {
            BC -!- GH -> {
                BH,
                GB -> BB,
                GL -> BL,
                GN -> BN,
            },
            GM -> {
                GB,
                GL,
                GN,
                BM,
            },
            GS -> BS,
        },
        GJ -> {
            GM,
            GS,
            BJ,
        },
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I think I understand what's happening. The node `GJ` is simply pushed ro the right to create space for the rest of the tree. I was wondering if there is a way to make the graph more compact, with each level horizontally aligned. Also, I was wondering how could I shift (horizontally, vertically) some node groups to express the logic in the graph; G(X)s should be in the same level and B(X)s should be below.

The proper graph layout is below and I used combination of `matrix` and `graphs`, which I am not entirely happy because it kind of defeats the usefulness of the `graphs` module itself.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `Layered layout` option, Wouldn't you preffer circular shapes for the nodes?, take note of the packages and compile with Lualatex as recommended in pgfmanual/tikz. :)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, graphs,graphdrawing, shapes.geometric }
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\begin{document}

%Compile with luaLatex
\begin{tikzpicture}
   
        \graph[
          layered layout, 
          sibling distance =3cm, 
          level distance =3cm, 
          edges={>=Latex, semithick, color=black},
          nodes={draw, ellipse, fill=black!10, very thick,
         minimum width=2cm, minimum height=10mm}
         ]
        {
        GC -> {
            BC -!- GH -> {
                BH,
                GB -> BB,
                GL -> BL,
                GN -> BN,
            },
            GM -> {
                GB,
                GL,
                GN,
                BM,
            },
            GS -> BS,
        },
        GJ -> {
            GM,
            GS,
            BJ,
        },
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I’ve got an error loading `graphdrawing` as well as error in the line with `\usegdlibrary`. There’s a separate chapter related to graph drawing in the manual you mentioned, which points out libraries compiled either in lua or C++ but I couldn’t understand that part enough. How shall I compile the libraries? As to the graph, circular shape would also work but I was making this as an exercise and wanted to reproduced the exact shape I found in the book. Thanks.

Comment: I missed the bit regarding `lualatex`. It's working now and it's almost like the original picture. Any idea how to control graph levels, for instance `GXes` and `BXes` need to be on separate levels. Also, can this be done without using `lualatex`? I have a template for a document which is supposed to be compiled by `pdflatex`. Thanks.

Comment: You grasped the sense of not going with Lua, it's just harder and longer, LuaLatex comes with almost any distribution, esentially it's a part of the package of using latex and tikz which is your purpose, almost anything compiled with pdflatex can be seamless compiled in lualatex save some older tex files, however if your tex templete constrains you, the output may be saved as an svg or png file and inserted as an image, regarding levels just add the key `\graph[levels sep = someunit]` options in page 423 pgf manual [link](https://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your comment and help :) The good news is `lualatex` is working and I have decided to stick to it, then. I will fiddle with the graph a little bit more and see what else I can do. Since `graphdrawing` is working I can't wait to see what else it can bring!

Comment: <3 consider accepting the answer as valid!

Comment: Just realised one thing. Currently, some nodes such as `G` and `B` are placed in the same level while `B` should be below a corresponding `G` and another group of `G`s should be below `B`, etc.. If I could position those, that would be perfect.